# Incorporate excel file to project directory wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, excel

I have some information stored in an excel file and I want to read them from a Wpf application. I'm able to read from this file in this way:

```
foreach (var worksheet in Workbook.Worksheets("ExcelFile.xlsx") )
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < 30; j++)
            {
                _Data.Add(new Data
                {  FirstElement = worksheet.Rows[j].Cells[0].Text.ToString(), });
            }
        }
```

Where ExcelFile.xlsx is a file saved in the Solution Folder and set as Incorporated Resource. 
If I start the application directly from Visual Studio it works but if I copy the compiled .exe file and I send it to someone, it doesn't work because the xlsx file is missing.

My question: is there a way to incoporate the xlsx file into the .exe file so that I can share only the .exe file and everything works?
Why setting the ExcelFile.xlsx file as "**incorporated Resource**" is not working as I thought?

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it by adding the file to your project and changing it's Build Action property to Embedded Resource.

You can then manifest the file as a temporary file on the user's hard drive like this:

```
// Create the template as a temporary file
string pathTemplate = Path.GetTempFileName();
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using (Stream input = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Vol_Report.Vol Report Template.xlsm")) // Note that it is Vol_Report because my namespace was Vol Report
using (Stream output = File.Create(pathTemplate))
{
    input.CopyTo(output);
}
```

And then read the file like this

```
app = new Excel.Application();
app.DisplayAlerts = false;
Excel.Workbooks books = app.Workbooks;
book = books.Open(pathTemplate);
```

Note the above code snippet assumes `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`.

Then at the end you can delete the temporary file like this

```
File.Delete(pathTemplate);
```

However, I need to manipulate the file and write to the file. Since you are just reading from the file there might be an easier way. Try adding the file as a project resource by right clicking on your project, choosing properties and clicking add resource -> add existing file under the resources tab. Then you should be able to get to your file like

```
Workbook.Worksheets(Properties.Resources.ExcelFile)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I have to read only the file, I tried your last option but I wasn't able to let it work. Using Workbook.Worksheets(Properties.Resources.ExcelFile) give me an error because I need a string as argument for Workbook.Worksheets .. Anyway I solved the problem by reading from a txt file instead of an Excel file. In this way it's easier. Thanks!